# Alternative to TextArea with more control over text?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am working on a chat project,  and have mostly finished everything that I needed.  My chat box is a textarea and for the most part it works, until I wanted to implement changing the color of certain words in the chatbox by using regex.

But looking at how I have this set up:

```
function writeMessageToChatBox(message, from, serverMessage=false, direct=false){
        let chat_box = $('#chatbox');
        let val = chat_box.val();
        if(!serverMessage){
            if(direct){
                console.log(replay);
                if(replay){
                    chat_box.val(val + '[Whisper to: ' + tempRecepient + ' ] ' + from + ": " + message + "\n" );
                    replay = false;
                    tempRecepient = undefined
                }
                else{
                    chat_box.val(val + '[Whisper from: ' + from + ' ] ' + from + ": " + message + "\n" );
                }
            }
            else{
                chat_box.val(val + from + ": " + message + "\n");
            }
        }
        else{
            chat_box.val(val + message + "\n");
        }
        chat_box.scrollTop(document.getElementById("chatbox").scrollHeight);
```

I've come to realize that textareas hold text within them in their value, but the text are not elements within the textarea so I cannot pick and choose which text gets style. From some research I saw that what I'm trying to do is not possible with a textarea.   What would be another option, I assume a div container that can hold text elements?

Comment: you can use div with contenteditable

Comment: You have 3 consecutive `else`... how's that working out for you?

Comment: @zer00ne They've been working fine for the most part, everything I wanted the chat client to do works. It's just I can't really give the text  style products and looking around the div contenteditable route seems even more rough.

Comment: @Jude `contenteditable` is easier (not by much) with `execCommand()`. I'd reconsider using all of those `else`s it looks like a `switch()` with no `break`s -- a fall through.

Comment: @Jude if receiving a whisper what condition must happen for it to happen? Is there anything that should happen for this to happen: `val + from + ": " + message + "\n"` or this: `val + message + "\n"`? The `chat_box.scrollTop(document.getElementById("chatbox").scrollHeight);` are those jQuery properties or JavaScript? I ask these questions because I'm almost done with an answer.

Comment: @zer00ne For a whisper, the server is sent JSON that contains information on the type of message, there is a field in the JSON called "type" and when it is set to 'direct' that means the message is a whisper.  `val + from + ": " + message + "\n"` is when a message is marked 'all' which means every one in the chatroom can see the message, but the message is not a server message.  ` val + message + "\n"` is a server response like "--- has joined the chatroom".  Lastly, `chat_box.scrollTop` is JQuery, but  `document.getElementById().scrollHeight` is just normal JS

Comment: @Jude Got it. Ok, answer is ready. I had to fudge some things not connected to any server of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`contenteditable` Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)

Refactored the function but I had to guess on some parameters. Used [**Template Literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which are Strings on steroids -- they should be your best friend dealing with all that text. The method `html()` is used extensively so markup can be typed or inserted in as a string.

### Demo

```js
function writeMessage(message, from = '', reply = '', serverMessage = false, direct = false) {
  let tempRx = '';
  let chat = $('.chatbox');
  let val = chat.text();
  if (!serverMessage) {
    if (direct) {
      console.log(reply);
      if (reply) {
        chat.html(`${val} <mark>[Whisper to: ${tempRx} ]</mark> ${from}: ${message}<br>`);
        reply = false;
        tempRx = undefined;
      } else {
        chat.html(`${val} <mark>[Whisper from: ${from} ]</mark> ${from}: ${message}<br>`);
      }
    } else {
      chat.html(`${val} ${from}: ${message}<br>`);
    }
  } else {
    chat.html(`${val} ${message}<br>`);
  }
  chat.scrollTop(chat[0].scrollHeight);
}

writeMessage(`Whispering, whisper test, mumble test, <b style='color:red'>belch test</b>, `, `<b style='color:green'>Rusty</b>`, 'reply', false, direct = true);
```

```html
<form id='main' name='main'>
  <fieldset class='chatbox' contenteditable='false'>
    <legend>Status: </legend>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class='chatbox' contenteditable>
  </fieldset>

</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great I assume I would have to put in handlers to stop the user from being able to edit the text in the fieldset element?

Comment: I just added another one with `contenteditable='false'` you can keep it that way so users can't tamper with it or if you want to have it a two-way thing using a handler would suffice. I suggest using `chat[0].toggleAttribute('contenteditable')`

Comment: Ah I'm just a little bit confused, I assume the first one with `contenteditable='false'` is what users would see and thus they cannot click/manipulate the text in there. But t he second one, which can be manipulated is that suppose to be like a box to send the message?

Just making sure so it all makes sense, I was using a text area also for my box that the user sends text  in but I guess having both be fieldsets would be better.

Comment: You are correct...that's very odd, look at the HTML of both chat boxes the first one has a legend with the text: "Status:" But the second doesn't have a legend yet it has the text "Status" as well?? Oh Ok I see it's: `let val = chat.text();`

Comment: Yea that is strange, I would say  perhaps the js is using the one with a legend twice, but one box is editable and the other isn't so I don't think thats the case.

Comment: It's actually `${val}`

Answer (score 4):

Use, `<div>` with `contenteditable` attribute.

```css
.textarea{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='textarea' contenteditable>

</div>
```

Comment: If I wanted to make it as close as possible to a readonly textarea would I have to handle as many interaction events as possible?